# MyBatis and Generics: Return Type ArrayList<? extends MyClass> Returns Nulls

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, wildcard, mybatis

I'm trying to use MyBatis to return a type that is extended from a super class:

**Mapper.java**

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM ${type} WHERE objectId >= ${start} AND objectId <= ${end}")
ArrayList<? extends ContentProviderBean> getFeed(@Param("type") String type, @Param("start") int start, @Param("end") int end);
```

But it returns an `ArrayList` of `null`s.

The DAO used to access this uses the same extends wildcard syntax, so I'm assuming that the problem is that MyBatis mappers don't like it.  I haven't been able to find any documentation saying that this is the case, however.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or a possible work-around to this problem?

Comment: How is mybatis suppose to know which type of ContentProviderBean to return? ${type} isn't enough information. Normally you would use @TypeDiscriminator but this would only be based on column.

Answer (score 2):

You may try adding type to result columns and configure @TypeDiscriminator to provide mybatis with hints which class to instantiate:

```
@Select("SELECT t.*, ${type} as type_discriminator" + 
        " FROM ${type} as t " +
        " WHERE objectId >= ${start} AND objectId <= ${end}")
@TypeDiscriminator(column = "type_discriminator",
    cases = {
        @Case (value="SomeContentProviderBeanSubclass", 
               type=SomeContentProviderBeanSubclass.class,
            results={
                @Result(property="someField", column="some_field"),
                // other columns mapping
        }),
        @Case (value="OtherContentProviderBeanSubclass", 
               type=OtherContentProviderBeanSubclass.class,
            results={
                @Result(property="otherField", column="other_field"),
        }),
        // @Cases for other ContentProviderBean subclasses
})
ArrayList<? extends ContentProviderBean> getFeed(@Param("type") String type,
       @Param("start") int start, @Param("end") int end);
```

Note that value attribute in Case should match the type param of getFeed.

There are several pitfalls you may encounter:

1. necessity to duplicate result fields mappings for many types
2. it is impossible to use automatic columns mapping when using mybatis annotations

You may try to overcome these problems by using xml mapping configuration. It may look like:

```
<resultMap id="resultContentProviderBean"
           type="ContentProviderBean"
           autoMapping="true">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <discriminator javaType="string" column="employee_type">
        <case value="SomeContentProviderBeanSubclass"
              resultType="SomeContentProviderBeanSubclass"
              autoMapping="true"/>
        <case value="OtherContentProviderBeanSubclass" 
              resultType="OtherContentProviderBeanSubclass"
              autoMapping="true"/>
    </discriminator>
</resultMap> 

<select id="getFeed" resultMap="resultContentProviderBean">
    SELECT t.*, ${type} as type_discriminator
      FROM ${type} as t 
    WHERE objectId >= ${start} AND objectId <= ${end}
</select>
```